# Does this water filter look clogged?

Tags: appliances, refrigerator, water-filtration

My refrigerator uses EveryDrop water filters like these:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00VBP8QPO/ref=oh_aui_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VBP8QPO)

The refrigerator is brand new, and I am already on the 2nd filter. The one that came with the fridge was already really slow flowing when I first hooked it up. The 2nd filter is pictured below. It lasted for a few weeks flowing OK before the fridge then started saying the filter was clogged. My whole house is already on a central filter: https://www.whirlpoolwatersolutions.com/products/central-water-filtration-system/

So I have a hard time believing that the filter is actually clogging up. Does this looked clogged to you all? I broke the housing so I could inspect what was inside the filter. Is the refrigerator lying to me about the filter needing to be replaced (A kitchenaid)?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the make and model of your refrigerator?

Comment: It is a KitchenAide KRFF707ESS

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look clogged, however, your fridge is probably on a use "timer". Basically it senses how much water flows through the filter. This includes both ice maker and water dispenser. You can try to just reset your filter warning light and see. If the flow of water is reduced, then it might be clogged. If you have a whole home filter system, you might be able to get a bypass filter for your fridge, or, like I did with mine, cut the line on the fridge from the valve to the filter, and the filter to the ice maker and dispenser, and connect them together. Now my water (RO system under sink) goes from the input valve at the back bottom of the fridge, straight to the valve for the ice maker and dispenser, effectively bypassing the filter. I then just "reset" the filter change light when it comes on. No water passes through the filter, so its not sensing a clogged filter, just sensing the amount of water used.